# Hide side-bar Menu-Toggle when page is loaded

Tags: menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle, sidebar

I have a hopefully a comprehensive and easy question using the bootstrap 3 framework and side-bar menu-toggle...Currently the side-bar menu is open when my site is launched, and then I can toggle closed once page is loaded...but I was wondering how to reverse this so that the sidebar menu is closed when the page is first loaded?
Below are the JS frameworks I am using and if more code is needed to understand this question I would be happy to provide it, but thought this may be universal within the bootstrap framwork...thanks in advance!
Here is the starting template code and the link...
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

```
HTML:
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
<div class="toggled">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                        <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>


    CSS:
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing your bootply or bin and the html and css. The thing is Bootstrap does not provide a sidebar menu in their default stuff, it's something you can add, off hand, no one is going to know what you intend unless you show code and a link to that code.

Comment: ok makes sense, I have added the html and css. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery on click event attached to #menu-toggle, is the magic that opens and closes your menu.  This handler simply adds or removes the toggled class to the element on your page with an id of wrapper.

To make the menu closed when the page is loaded, just **add the toggled class to the wrapper div in your markup**:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" class="toggled">

        <!-- ...the rest of your markup here -->

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have added the html and css which hopefully adds clarity to my question...thanks

Comment: It's not shown in your markup that you've added, but there is an element in your html that has an id="wrapper".  Based on the css you've now included, the .toggled class is what opens the sidebar navigation, so if you're saying that the sidebar is opened when you load the page, and *there's no other js that is adding that class*, then the class is probably in your html markup. To have the sidebar in its collapsed state when you load the page, you should remove the .toggled class from the element with the wrapper id.

Comment: Ok, everything you explained makes perfect sense but I tried removing the .toggled classes from my mark up and didn't seem to work so I am probably just missing something due to mixing some themes and style sheets...I edited my question post with the start theme template I used from the bootstrap site for reference on how I would have the initial state side-menu as collapsed, so perhaps this may be easier to do from the basic start bootstrap template and then apply to my edits...appreciate your help thus far!

Comment: I had it backwards: add the class toggled to make the menu closed.